# Combine Pmwiki with CMS

Tags: content-management-system, pmwiki

Currently we have a website based on Pmwiki, which needs to be expanded. The idea is to combine it with a CMS, something like Joomla. So we keep the data and wiki functionalities, while introducing user authentication system, discussion forum and other features.

The question is, where should I start looking into the problem? Is there any books or blogs about how to combine web frameworks? Any suggestion will be really helpful!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? There has been some recent work using external auth systems.

Answer (score 0):

PmWiki **is** a CMS, so depending upon what you want/need to do, you could extend PmWiki to do all of those things.

It comes with user authentication, and there are extensions ("[recipes](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/Cookbook)") for forums, blogs and other features.

Have a look at the entries under [Administration](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/Administration) which include a lot of variations on authentication (and other tasks).

You should also look at [CMS category](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/CMS).